# jQuery $("img[src=the_image_souce]").attr('src','new_src'); does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My code does not work I don't know why
the_image_source and new_src are just place holders I have put real values in them

I have also tried `$("img[src=the_image_souce]")[0].attr('src','new_src');` but it does not work either, please help

Comment: solved!, i simple changed $ to jQuery and i removed (new date()).getTime() too it wasn't required and the code works fine thank you so much for your help anyways guys :) alas i can't vote you up :s

Comment: @user478903  Curiousity has me now.  In the title you typed the line of code as this $("img[src=the_image_souce]").attr('src','new_src');  but then in the description you typed it like this $("img[src=the_image_souce]")[0].attr('src','new_src');  So which is the actual code you are using.  Note the difference is [0] after the selector.

Comment: i just did a spelling mistake in the title

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must be aware by accessing the [0] element in the jQuery Object this will return the DOM element.  You cannot use the jQuery attr() method directly on a DOM element. It must be run on a jQuery Object

Essentially, if you will have more than one element that matches the following selector and you want to access the first matched element `$("img[src='http://domain.com/image.jpg]")` then you should use [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) or [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). Example

```
$("img[src='http://domain.com/image.jpg']").first().attr('src','http://domain.com/newimage.jpg')
```

or

```
$("img[src='http://domain.com/image.jpg']").eq(0).attr('src','http://domain.com/newimage.jpg')
```

or

```
$($("img[src='http://domain.com/image.jpg']")[0]).attr('src','http://domain.com/newimage.jpg');
```

but this just looks strange

Comment: I guess `:first` is a bit more optimized

Comment: Accidentally hit down, fixed it ;)

Comment: Why would adding `.first()` or `eq(0)` cause the selector to work?

Comment: @patrick ..Ok maybe I didnt word it correctly but his original statment was $("img[src=the_image_souce]")[0].attr('src','new_src');  and putting [0] after the selector will return the DOM Element.  Because of this .attr() will not function directly on a DOM Element.

Comment: Yes, but the code with `$("img[src=the_image_souce]")[0].attr(...` was just an addition to the code in the title.

Comment: @patrick yes your right...but in that case which is the typo...the title or the description?

Comment: I think the primary code was in the title, but that is a really poor place for it. The code in the question seemed to be a secondary attempt since it states *"I've also tried..."*. Anyway, this question had the markings of having the actual issue edited out, which apparently it did. :o)

Comment: i did for a quick reply, and perhaps i got alot :o

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what browser and jQuery versions? Also, what's not working, the selector, setting the attribute, or leading the new image? Start simple, what does alert($("img[src=imgsrc])] show you? Also what does firebugs say is in the DOM after that code runs?

Answer (score 0):

Not for nothing but attribute selector isn't properly written. The `"` is important. Therefor you need:

```
$('img[src="the_image_source"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a relative path  as image-src, it depends on the browser, what he will retrieve as src. Most Browsers will return the absolute path, not the relative path, so your match fails.

You can only compare the end of the src:

```
$("img[src$='the_image_source']").attr('src','new_src');
```

But if you have more images with the same filename in different directories, this may force unexpected results. The best way I think is to use always absolute path inclusive protocol & domain as img-src and in jQuery-selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do what WaldenL suggests and break it down piece by piece to find out what exactly is not working. First check your selector.

```
alert($("img[src=the_image_source]").length);
```

if that is greater than zero, then your selector is good. if not, then try using the id of the tag (if you know it) or some other way of getting that image tag.

if the selector is good, then there's something wrong with setting the src attribute. Make sure the value of new_src is valid and that you're not doing something silly like putting quotes around your variable or misspellings like this:

```
var the_image_source = "http://mysite/images/img01.gif";
var new_src = "http://mysite/images/img02.gif";
$('img[src=the_image_souce]').attr('src','new_src'); // won't work - first variable is missing the "r" and not formatted correctly and attr setter has parenthesis
$('img[src=' + the_image_source + ']').attr('src',new_src); // should work
```

Also, make sure you have it inside the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var the_image_source = "http://mysite/images/img01.gif";
    var new_src = "http://mysite/images/img02.gif";
    $('img[src=' + the_image_source + ']').attr('src',new_src);
});
```

Comment: i didn't had it document ready function, though i will do it now thanks!