# Selecting image using $('img[src$="image source end string in variable"]') getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code wherein there's an image in id `#imgfullview` and images on class `imglist`.

I want to get the image src of `#imgfullview` and get the matching image on class imglist base on src attribute.

I used this selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector

This is working if i just used selector using string

```
var x = $(".imglist[src$='b-640x624.jpg']");
var imglistmatched = x.attr("src");
alert(imglistmatched );
```

But if I used a selector changing the string to variable, I'm getting `undefined value` not sure why though I have exact string as `'b-640x624.jpg'` on variable `splitimgurl` from string split function based on full patch src or through assigning the exact string if I check it on console.log or alert the variable

```
var currentimg =$("#imgfullview").attr("src");
var splitimgpath = currentimg.split('_');
var splitimgurl = splitimgpath[2]; //or this splitimgurl = "b-640x624.jpg";
var x = $(".imglist[src$=splitimgurl]");
var imglistmatched = x.attr("src");
alert (imglistmatched);
```

I tried this

```
var x = $(".imglist[src$="splitimgurl"]");
```

and this

```
var x = $(".imglist[src$="+splitimgurl+"]");
```

and this

```
var x = $(".imglist[src$=""+splitimgurl]");
```

it does not work

Please see this on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w7n3sh2v/

I found the related question below but it does not help

[jQuery $("img[src=the_image_souce]").attr('src','new_src'); does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956157/jquery-imgsrc-the-image-souce-attrsrc-new-src-does-not-work)

May I know if there's a correct way to put variable on Attribute Equals Selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `''` in the

```
var x = $(".imglist[src$=" + splitimgurl + "]");
```

Try this

```
var x = $(".imglist[src$='" + splitimgurl + "']");
```